# Extract value from JSON and use in another exec

Tags: gatling

New to Gatling.

My use case is I need to dynamically setup a URL. For e.g, `POST` to `/Subscribers` that will return a `subscriberUrl` and then use `subscriberUrl` for load testing.

It is not obvious from the documentation how to accomplish this. So a single POST followed by multiple GETS on the resulting Url from the previous POST.

Is this sort of a use case that is supported by Gatling ? From the documentation it feels that you need to model business process as scenarios and call business process 'n' times (and of-course parameters). Am looking for ways to combine two scenarios here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what Gatling is built for. It's simple:

```
 val subscribe = exec(http("Subscribe")
   .post("/Subscribers")
   .body(StringBody(auth))
   .check(status.is(200))
   .check(jsonPath("$.subscriberUrl")
         .saveAs("subscriberUrl"))
 )
```

Then later `.get("${subscriberUrl}")`